# create a dictionary from a list with a function

Tags: python, pandas, list, dictionary

I'm working on a premier league dataset and I need to create a dictionary where the keys are the teams and the values are their relative points. I have a list for the teams and a function that takes the results from the matches and transform them into the points for the teams. I got everything good but the problem is that instead of creating one dictionary with all the teams and their scores, it prints 20 dictionaries for each of the team. What is wrong?

[image]

Comment: Code as text not images please!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are creating a new dictionary at each iteration. Instead you should make the dictionary before the loop and then add a new entry at each iteration:

```
def get_team_points(df, teams):
    team_points = {}
    for team_name in teams:
        num_points = ... # as you have it but since you posted an image I'm not rewriting it
        team_points[team_name] = num_points
    return team_points
```

A neater solution is to use a dictionary comprehension

```
def get_team_points(df, teams):
    team_points = {team: get_num_points(team, df) for team in teams}
    return team_points
```

where `get_num_points` is a function of your `num_points = ...` line, which again I would type out if you had posted the code as text :)

Also - please start using better variable names ;) your life will improve if you do. Names like List and Dict are really bad since:

1. they're not descriptive
2. they shadow build-in classes from the typing module (which you should use)
3. they violate pep8 naming conventions

and speaking of the typing module, here it is in action:

```
def get_team_points(df: pd.DataFrame, teams: List[str]) -> Dict[str, int]:
    team_points = {team: get_num_points(team, df) for team in teams}
    return team_points
```

now you can use a tool like mypy to catch errors before they occur. If you use an IDE instead of jupyter, it will highlight errors as you go. And also your code becomes much clearer for other developers (including future you) to understand and use.

Comment: Thank you so much for your advices! I'm sorry for the image but I'm new to stack overflow, I'll put codes next time

Comment: It's not too late - you can edit your question and replace the image with text :)

Answer (score 3):

I think perhaps you want this:

```
def get_team_points(df, teams):
    Dict = {}
    for team_name in List:
        num_points = TeamPoints(...)
        Dict[team_name] = num_points
    print(Dict)
```

Answer (score 2):

In TeamsPointDict() method, you are creating dictionaries for each team member in the list.
To insert all of them in one dictionary, declare the dictionary outside the for loop.

Answer (score 2):

You want to take the sum of HP for Home teams, and AP for Away teams and add them together by team. Instead of manually separating, you can use two groupby operations and sum the results.

The return of each `groupby` will be a Series that we can then add together as pandas aligns on the index (teams in this case). Then with `Series.to_dict()` we get the entire dictionary at once.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'HomeTeam': list('AABCDA'), 'AwayTeam': list('CBAAAB'),
                   'HP': [4,5,6,7,8,10], 'AP': [0,0,10,11,4,7]})

  HomeTeam AwayTeam  HP  AP
0        A        C   4   0
1        A        B   5   0
2        B        A   6  10
3        C        A   7  11
4        D        A   8   4
5        A        B  10   7
```

---

```
# Fill value so addition works if a team has exclusively home/away games.
s = df.groupby('HomeTeam')['HP'].sum().add(df.groupby('AwayTeam')['AP'].sum(),
                                           fill_value=0).astype(int)

s.to_dict()
{'A': 44, 'B': 13, 'C': 7, 'D': 8}
```

Answer (score 1):

you should define your dictionary before the function then add your values.

```
dic = {}
for team_name in List:
    dic[team_name] = num_points
```